# Java -- wait method not exiting

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create a general purpose `MessagePrinter` class that handles multiple threads that each print out a message every  seconds. Also, there's a manager thread that keeps track of time and wakes up each thread every second, and after each thread is woken up each thread needs to check whether it's time to print the message.

However, there's one main bug -- when I call the `wait()` function when waiting to be woken up, the `wait()` function isn't quitting. I've searched on Google, but to no avail. Below is the code.

```
import java.util.*;

class MonitorCondition {}

public class MessagePrinter implements Runnable {
    private static int time = 0;
    private MonitorCondition mc = new MonitorCondition();

    private int elapse;
    private String title;
    private boolean signaled;

    public MessagePrinter(int elapse, String title) {
        this.elapse = elapse;
        this.title = title;
        new Thread(this, title).start();
        this.signaled = false;
    }

    // http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html
    public void run() {
        if(!title.equals("manager")) {
            while(true) {
                synchronized(mc) {
                    while(!signaled) {
                        try { mc.wait(); }
                        // Now check whether we can print.
                        catch(InterruptedException e) {;}
                    }
                    if(time % elapse == 0) 
                        System.out.println(elapse + " second message!");
                    signaled = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            while(true) {
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } // REGARDLESS of what elapse is set to
                catch(InterruptedException e) {;}
                synchronized(mc) {
                    System.out.println(++time);
                    signaled = true;
                    mc.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessagePrinter m1 = new MessagePrinter(1, "manager");
        MessagePrinter m2 = new MessagePrinter(7, "client1");
        MessagePrinter m3 = new MessagePrinter(5, "client2");
    }
}
```

The code is hanging on this line: `try { mc.wait(); }`. Perhaps it's a problem with how I use the synchronized blocks, but I've seen questions on producer-consumer in Java, and this looks exactly how it's supposed to be implemented according to the answers -- but this hasn't fixed the hanging `wait()` function issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `wait()` do? What are you `synchronized` on? Is it shared?

Comment: Wait, I found another problem. The 7-second printer only catches times 1, 3, 5, 7, ... and the 5-second printer only catches 2, 4, 6, 8, ... or vice versa (when the 5-second printer "beats" the 7-second printer) to printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of MessagePrinter will have its own copy of the field mc, thus each thread is entering a different monitors wait method. Calling notifyAll() does nothing because no one will ever be waiting on the managers mc monitor. Make mc static.

Edit - even though you accepted the answer already, I thought I would put this out there because your going to run into it. When you call .notifyAll() in the manager thread, it will notify all the threads waiting on that objects monitor, but only one will be able to require the lock at any given time. There is no guarantee which will acquire the lock, only that one will at any given time. That thread will release the lock then if the condition is true, it will reset signaled to false. In the mean time, one of the other threads will have woken up, and could be evaluating your while condition shortly AFTER the signaled flag was reset to false, meaning one or more of your clients may fail to print their message.

Here is an example of how it manifests in the applications output after a while of running:

```
7 second message!
561
562
563
564
565
5 second message!
566
567
568
569
570
571
572
573
574
7 second message!
575
5 second message!
```

Comment: `Make mc static.` Or create a `MonitorCondition` object which you share with all `Runnable` instances by having them store it in an instance field.

Comment: O.K., thanks. However, now the `while(!signaled) {` loop isn't exiting; `signaled` should be setting to true. But you answered my question and so accepting it.

Comment: Its the same story with signaled, different instances. You will need to be able to figure out how to signal each client by referencing their instance of signaled, which in this case is probably also just making it static volatile, or using Sotirios suggestion.

Comment: OK, so I'll remember to always make shared stuff static when doing concurrency in Java. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user2748947 I edited it with a quick note about the logic you should take a look at.

Comment: Yes, I was just experiencing that issue.
EDIT: Wait, but when I create two clients, 7 and 15, the 7 second message still fails to print out even after I change notifyAll() to notify(). Is that sufficient, or is there something else?

Comment: I think you should play with it more and figure it out :D